# C++ - Proper method to use delete while creating a vector of class objects

Tags: c++, class, vector

I saw a few examples of creating a vector of class objects and many of them uses a pointer and `new` keyword. However, in many cases the `delete` is not used to free up memory allocated by `new`. I would like to know if the following piece of code uses `delete` properly.

I have a class `Marker`:

```
class Marker{

    public:
        Marker(int, float, float);
        int marker_id();

    private:
        int id;
        float mx;
        float my;
};
```

It's constructor is:

```
Marker::Marker(int idno, float x, float y){

    //ctor
    id = idno;
    mx = x;
    my = y;
}
```

I need a vector `marker_vec` with objects or instances of `Marker` class. Hence, I wrote the following piece of code:

```
vector <Marker> marker_vec;

Marker *m = new Marker(last_id, m_x, m_y);
marker_vec.push_back(*m);
delete m;
```

If I use the above code in a loop to create `marker_vec[0]` and `marker_vec[1]`, I believe that the `delete` wouldn't delete them and will only free up the pointer `m`. Is there any disadvantages for the above method?

Comment: You can do this, but I don't see why you don't just say `marker_vec.emplace_back(Marker(last_id, m_x, m_y));` (or push_back). It's ok to not use pointers if your object is cheap to copy (and yours is). You also want to use pointers if you're storing `OVERLAPPED` structures (I had an annoying bug to track down because the memory in them has to stay in the same place and my vector was copying them all over the place).

Comment: Why so convoluted? Why not just `marker_vec.emplace_back(last_id, m_x, m_y);`?

Comment: There is no need for pointers at all in the code you posted.

Comment: I didn't know about `emplace_back` and  I saw something similar in an example: [link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/63358-store-class-objects-in-vector/). So, basically I can replace the 3 lines after vector declaration, using `marker_vec.emplace_back(Marker(last_id, m_x, m_y));`?

Comment: Also, if the object was not cheap to copy is the above method using pointers better than `emplace_back`?

Comment: At the end, you have to add `m=nullptr;` but no need to pointer for your code at all here.

Comment: @H.DJEMAI You don't have to add `m = nullptr;`. That's a style suggested by a lot of people (though I don't subscribe to it if the object is going out of scope). Syamprasad: Not really, because you're still sticking RAII `Marker` objects into the vector. If the object is not cheap to copy, you'll want to create an `std::vector<Marker*>` instead of an `std::vector<Marker>`.

Comment: Don't do `emplace_back(Marker(` -- that would create a `Marker` just to copy (or move) it. Look at what Kerrek SB suggested.

Comment: @David Schwartz: If I use that method, how can the vector elements be `Marker` objects? This class has other functions that I will be using on these elements.

Comment: @SyamprasadKR The vector elements are still `Marker` objects. `emplace_back` forwards its parameters to the appropriate constructor for the element type (in this case `Marker`). My code causes the copy or move constructor to be called, so Kerrek's is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code is alright, since when you push_back, the contents referenced by the m pointer will be copied and added as the last element of the `vector`. You're doing good by deallocating the memory you set properly (for every **new** there is a corresponding **delete**).

```
vector <Marker> marker_vec;

Marker *m = new Marker(last_id, m_x, m_y);
marker_vec.push_back(*m);
delete m;
```

I just think it's unnecessary for you to use pointers in this case having one type of Marker class and your `std::vector` of type `<Marker>`.

I would personally improve the implementation of this code to being statically instantiated. It's simple and cleaner in this case:

```
vector <Marker> marker_vec;

Marker m(last_id, m_x, m_y);
marker_vec.push_back*m);
```

However, if you maybe had inheritance like different type of markers:

```
class HighlighterMarker : public Marker { };
```

and

```
class PenMarker: public Marker { };
```

Only then, it'd make sense for you to use dynamic memory and your vector to be declared as:

`std::vector <Marker*> marker_vec`. This one can store all your references to any type of derived class `Marker`,